# Drawing simple rectangles in my JPanel doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, awt

The end goal for this code so far is to draw a bunch of rectangles that slowly increase in height (from left to right across the window), so that it forms sort of a right triangle of rectangles, that takes up the bottom right half of the window. Code compiles fine, but when when run, all the window displays is a JFrame named "Selection Sort" with a dark gray background (all fine, that's what it's supposed to do), and no rectangles (not fine). Code for the 2 classes:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SelectionSort extends JPanel {

    private Bar arr[];
    private JFrame frame; 
    private int amountBars;

    public SelectionSort(int amountBars) {
        frame = new JFrame("Selection Sort");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(700, 500);
        setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        frame.setContentPane(this);
        this.amountBars = amountBars;
        arr = new Bar[amountBars];
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            arr[i] = new Bar(new Color(i, i, i), i);
        }
        paintComponent(frame, getGraphics());
        }

    public void paintComponent(JFrame frame, Graphics g) {
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            g.setColor(arr[i].getColor());
            g.fillRect(i * ((int) getSize().getWidth() / arr.length), (int) getSize().getHeight(), (int) (getSize().getWidth() / arr.length), i * ((int) getSize().getHeight() / arr.length));
        }
    }

    private void delay(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SelectionSort sort = new SelectionSort(100);
        sort.repaint();
    }

}


public class Bar {

    private int size;
    private Color color;
    private int listNum;

    public Bar(Color color, int listNum) {
        this.color = color;
        this.listNum = listNum;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public int getListNum() {
        return listNum;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void setListNum(int listNum) {
        this.listNum = listNum;
    }
}
```

I have some thoughts on how to do this differently, but I thought I'd just ask at this point to see. If this isn't solved, then would putting a drawRect method IN my Bar class, and then saying `arr[i].draw(getGraphics)`  in the paintComponent method, or something like that work better?
Note, the color of the bar is not important rn, but also how would I make it a rainbow gradient across the window? I don't think `new Color(i, i, i)` will work. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `getGraphics()` to do painting. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a JPanel. Then you add the panel to the frame. Swing will then pass the Graphics object to the paintComponent() method whenever it determines the component needs to be repainted. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: In Oracle's tutorial on custom painting, they make an entirely separate JPanel class. Do I have to separate my class into 2 different classes as well? Or is there a way to do this in one class...

Edit: Nevermind. Problem solved!